# Sum, Sumifs or Sumproduct, not sure which one to use?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, sumifs

I have the following table:

```
    JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
A   10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 110 120
B   20  40  60  80  100 120 140 160 180 200 220 240
C   30  60  90  120 150 180 210 240 270 300 330 360
```

I am trying to get the total sum of what A would be from the beginning of the year to the current month. Let's take this month for example, I want the sum of what A would be from January to September.

Comment: You just and only published your requirements. What have you tried so far? We help in finding/debugging/improving solutions, but don´t deliver solutions as you order them ;)

Comment: I tried doing =SUMIFS(B1:M1,B2:M2,"<="&MONTH(NOW())), that gets me half of it. Do you think I should use a vlookup combination with it?

Comment: I also tried a sumproduct but keeps giving me a #value error.

Comment: edit your question (there's an `edit` label at the bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will return sum of values in JAN thru the current month.  I assumed table is at top of document and to the left.

A values:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B2:"&ADDRESS(2,MONTH(TODAY())+1,4)))
```

B values:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B3:"&ADDRESS(3,MONTH(TODAY())+1,4)))
```

C values:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B4:"&ADDRESS(4,MONTH(TODAY())+1,4)))
```

---

****EDIT****

To make it more dynamic, say you have in cell "H8" the value 'A' and want to return the A sum up to the current month, you can do it like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(H8,A1:A4,0)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(H8,A1:A4,0),MONTH(TODAY())+1,4)))
```

Comment: thanks! one other quick question. I see that it is searching the address of the a in row 2. but what if I wanted it to be more dynamic and search a reference. so lets say i had a in cell H8. and I wanted to search that table to add the figures from Jan to Sept where the figures match the cell H8.

Comment: See my edit (bottom of post).  As long as the value in 'H8' matches A, B or C you'll get that sum.

Answer (score 1):

`INDIRECT()` is your friend...

assuming you have your table at the top of the sheet and that A4 contains the month you want to stop...

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B2:"&A4&"2"))
```

if you want to add a dynamic twist to the formula, name your cells as MONTHVALUES, then you can get its address with `ROW(monthvalues)` and `COLUMN(monthvalues)`

and the current month column would become COLUMN(monthvalues)+MONTH(NOW())-1

and if you name a cell containing the desiredrow

so you can refer back to the range from january to column month of the desired row as

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(monthvalues)+desiredrow-1;COLUMN(monthvalues))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(monthvalues)+desiredrow-1;COLUMN(monthvalues)+MONTH(NOW()))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use INDEX and MATCH.

```
=SUM(B2:INDEX(B2:M2,1,MATCH(UPPER(TEXT(TODAY(),"MMM")),B1:M1,FALSE)))
```

See http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/using-indexmatch-as-a-cell-reference/ for more information.